# use debugger in matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging

i want to debug following simplest code in matlab and clarify why it executes always  if statement

```
function testfile(x)
if 3<x<6
disp('in the middle of range');
else
    disp('out of range');

end
end
```

i have  used  following code for debugger

```
echo testfile on
 testfile(-2)
in the middle of range


testfile(6)
in the middle of range
```

why it does not execute else  statement?i have used following code as a test

```
 5<4<8

ans =

     1
```

so does it mean that  writing  if statement in this style is  wrong?a i understood it  is  same as  if 5<4  || 4<8?then it makes clear for me why it  executes only  if statement and  never reaches to    else

Comment: This might be wrong so I don't like to put in as an answer but does `3<x<6` really work as you expect? I think it evaluates `3<x` first, returns a logical `1` which is then compared as `1<6` which returns another logical `1`. As I currently don't have Matlab installed I can't test it though.

Comment: i want to make familiar with  debug  statement and make clarify everything for me

Comment: If you want to debug code in Matlab, set a stop at the line of the `if` statement, and once you've entered debug mode, start evaluating statements and parts of statements on the command line, as well as inspecting values of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`5<4<8` is evaluated as `(5<4)<8`. If we resolve the expression in the parentheses first, we have `0<8`, which is true. Test with `5<4==0`, which evaluates to `true`.

What you want to do is check whether `x` is both bigger than 3 and smaller than 6, i.e.

`3<x && x<6`